# Remove link for mydomian.azurewebsites.net test web apps

Tags: asp.net, azure, search, azure-web-app-service

I running three azure web apps for developing stages. Dev, Demo and Prod. These are called ex. mydomian.azurewebsites.net

Then I have the main domain as www. mydomian.net

Now Dev, Demo and Prod beginning to appear on Google Search results, and I want that to be disabled. But not for the main domain www. mydomian.net

Is there any good solutions to that problem?

Comment: Adding robots.txt to your website asking search engines not to index your website. Will that work?

Comment: Will this not effect the main domain also? Or could I tell wich url not to add in google??

Answer (score 1):

If you do separate deploys for each instance you can manually manage a robot.txt file, but if (like me) when 'Demo' passes UAT you just swap it into the live site that won't work.

One solution, which is very easy if you are using some kind of Master Page, is to use 'sticky' AppSettings slots to determine when to insert the robots.txt into the instances html pages. You could also look at the url, but as this can change I prefer to go with sticky slots (tickable in the 'new' Azure portal)

Comment: I will try the Sticky AppSettings solution.. Thanks. Any good link to get me started?

Comment: This link is good: https://www.tekcent.com/articles/2013/dynamic-robots-exclusion-file-in-aspnet/

Comment: You can check out the docs here for sticky settings instructions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/#configuration-for-deployment-slots